# Apache mod_proxy_balancer + Tomcat load balancing - Should not redirect until web applications are ready

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, load-balancing, failover, mod-proxy

I am using **apache2** `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_balancer` to balance the load to 4 seperate **tomcat8** instances on different servers. I am using different **AJP** ports for each tomcat instance and using **jvmRoute** directive in tomcat `server.xml`, like this:
First instance:

```
<Connector port="[port1]" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="tomcat1">
```

Second instance:

```
<Connector port="[port2]" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="tomcat2">
```

And so on.

In apache2 configuration, i define a cluster, like this:

```
<Proxy balancer://myCluster>
        BalancerMember ajp://[ip1]:[port1] route=tomcat1 loadfactor=1
        BalancerMember ajp://[ip2]:[port2] route=tomcat2 loadfactor=1
        BalancerMember ajp://[ip3]:[port3] route=tomcat3 loadfactor=1
        BalancerMember ajp://[ip4]:[port4] route=tomcat4 loadfactor=1

        ProxySet lbmethod=bybusyness
        ProxySet stickysession=JSESSIONID

        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from none
        Allow from all
 </Proxy>
```

And the proxypass directives:

```
ProxyPass / balancer://myCluster/
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://myCluster/
...
```

It works as expected, does load balancing as it should, and if a Tomcat instance is down, load blaancer does not redirect to that instance. Everything is working well until this point.

But the problem is, when I trigger deployment on the tomcat instances, I stop them one by one, upload the new artifact and restart the instance. But the load balancer redirects the the tomcat instance even before web application artifacts get deployed, initialized and get ready. So, the user faces blank screen if he makes a request to an URL which is not ready yet.

How can I handle that situation to prevent redirection until web application is completely ready? How can I check the status of them?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best approach is to build a kind of status servlet that knows how to check if your desired context (war) is fully operational and utilize `failonstatus` directive.

Another option is to use http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html#balancer_manager in your deployment. Steps being:

- Disable a worker
- deploy
- Wait for it to be up/check
- Enable worker